# List of Parameters in a function VS2010

Tags: c#

Anyone knows if exist a Class, List, or whatelse that return me the list of the current parameters and values  in a current function?

Comment: I don't think pulling the parameter values is possible but reflection should be able to get you the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx) and then using [GetParameters()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) you can get information about the parameters.

You may use [ICorDebugILFrame::GetArgument Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231057.aspx) function that's actually capable of getting argument values.(*Although truly speaking I have never used this function*)

Comment: How does this address getting the parameter (and local variable) values? It has nothing to do with JIT optimization...

Comment: @leppie:- Updated my answer! I have never used but I have heard of [ICorDebugILFrame::GetArgument Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231057.aspx) I think this function is capable of getting argument values.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm try to use it but i can´t find the way... Can you show me an example of MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: RT, at last I've write a valid code witg GetParameters, but I have the name (Great!!!) but not the current value...
Do you know how?
Thanks!!!